# Local uniqueness in nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

I'm considering the nonlinear ODE

$$f''(t)+f(t)-\int_0^t f^3(s)ds=0$$

for $f\in C^{2,\gamma}([0,1])$, with Cauchy data $f(0)=u_0, f'(0)=u_1$.
With $X=C^{2,\gamma}([0,1])$ and $Y=C^{0,\gamma}([0,1])$, we may use the nonlinear operator
$F:X\rightarrow Y$ given by the formula

$$F[f](t)=f''(t)+f(t)-\int_0^t f^3(s)ds$$
and take its Fréchet derivative at the origin: $DF[0]:f\mapsto f''+f$. 
Using a variant of the contraction principle I have that $F$ is locally invertible in a neighborhood around the origin if $F[0]=0$ and $DF[0]$ is invertible. However, in this case $DF[0]$ is surjective, but has a two-dimensional kernel: $\ker DF[0]=\{a\cos t+b\sin t: a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Therefore, since $DF[0]$ is Fredholm I used the decomposition $X=\ker DF[0]\oplus X_1$ to conclude that the restriction of $F$ to $X_1$ is indeed locally invertible around zero.

What is left for me to do is to somehow show that if $|u_0|$ and $|u_1|$ are sufficiently small, then there exists a unique solution near the origin to the original equation. However, after trying for a few days I'm completely stuck. I tried the ansatz $f=f_0+f_1$, where $f_0$ is the part of $f$ in $\ker DF[0]$ and $f_1$ is the part of $f$ in $X_1$, but I just can't see it leading anywhere.

Alternatively, I tried to completely abandon the operator theory approach altogether and just use the original equation to state that if $F[f]=0$, then $f$ must be smooth. Then I derived formulas for $f^{(n)}$, $n>2$, in order to get an estimation of $|f^{(n)}(0)|$ so that I could potentially use convergence of a power series in my argument. However, I couldn't find an effective way to bound $|f^{(n)}(0)|$ sufficiently (although I checked numerically that $|f^{(n)}(0)|$ would indeed be sufficiently bounded for my purposes).

What is it that I'm missing? Is there another approach or detail that I'm seemingly blind to finish the argument off?

Comment: This is not an ODE, it's an integro-differential equation.  But you can differentiate to get
$f''' + f' - f^3 = 0$, which is a differential equation, and the standard existence and uniqueness theorem applies.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ok I see. I guess it doesn't really matter which solution space we're in as long as it contains the smooth functions, since only a smooth function could solve the equation to begin with, which means that it's ok to differentiate the equation. When you say the standard existence and uniqueness theorem, is there a specific name for it? I can't seem to find it for higher-order equations than second order, and I'd like to review the proof.

Comment: Sometimes called the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).  It's stated there for first-order differential equations, but higher-order equations are equivalent to first-order systems, and the theorem is essentially the same for systems.  See e.g. [Birkhoff and Rota](https://books.google.ca/books?id=yKGAwgEACAAJ), sec. V.9.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ok thanks. If I'm correct, this theorem assures me that the equation has a unique solution $f\in C([t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon])$ if $\epsilon>0$ is small enough, no matter what $u_0$ and $u_1$ is. But is there a way I could use this to conclude that there is a unique solution $f\in C([0,1])$ if $|u_0|$ and $|u_1|$ are sufficiently small?

Comment: This is a consequence of the Continuity Theorem (Theorem 2 of Birkhoff and Rota sec. V.3), which says that in a region where the system satisfies a Lipschitz condition with Lipschitz constant L, any two solutions $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ satisfy
$$ \|{\bf x}(a+h) - {\bf y}(a+h)\| \le e^{Lh} \|{\bf x}(a) - {\bf y}(a)\|$$